# How can I export zabbix database?

Tags: sql-server, database, zabbix

How can I get zabbix database ?
I want to export zabbix database and use it in SQLserver ?
I tried to install unixODBC but I didn't successed 
thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide us more information. What database system are you currently using? MS SQL? Or some other? So do you want to convert it from one database system to another or what's the issue? Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: I want to export all information in zabbix database for use it in SQLserver
thanks for your help

Comment: And what database does your current Zabbix server use?

Comment: I 'm verry sorry to see that but I don't know because I am beginner in database

Answer (score 1):

You can export your database using standard tools like [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) or [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgdump.html), depending on which backend database you are using currently.

Note that Zabbix does not support MS SQL Server as a backend, thus you will not be able to use Zabbix server/frontend with it - it would only make sense if you wanted to import history/trend data for separate analysis.